# how to load RTL style in RTL language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, theming

I have a multi language website, one of languages is a RTL language, in Drupal 7 I put my CSS in `style.css` and RTL CSS to `style-rtl.css` and by default drupal also load style-rtl.css file, Now **in Drupal 8 ,I have a multi language theme, how can I tell Drupal to load my RTL style in RTL language?**

**update**
I found [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2032405) but I am not sure about that because  I have a CSS file with almost 1400 lines, I should put [dir="rtl"] before all of any selector ? !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drupal 8 uses libraries, and you can load these in templates. One way of achieving language direction dependant libraries would be to use the `html_attributes['dir']` variable in `html.html.twig` and load different libraries depending on the value:

```
{% if html_attributes['dir'] == 'ltr' %}
  {{ attach_library('your_theme_name/styles') }}
{% elseif html_attributes['dir'] == 'rtl' %}
  {{ attach_library('your_theme_name/styles_rtl') }}
{%- endif -%}
```

Set up a couple of libraries:

```
styles:
  version: 8.x-1.0
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles.css: {}

styles_rtl:
  version: 8.x-1.0
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles-rtl.css: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for an alternative solution:

> You can also define a new `library` in `libraries.yml` file of your
>   theme and point that library to use a certain CSS or JS or whatever
>   you need.

Next step is to use a preprocess such as theme preprocess to tell Drupal8 to use that library in a specific condition.

**Example:**
Defining new library beneath your default one in `themename.libraries.yml`

```
rtl:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      assets/css/themename.style-rtl.css: {}
```

Next you can detect the current direction of your pages with a preprocess in `themename.theme` file:

```
function themename_preprocess_html (&$variables) {
    // Load specific library for pages with html attribute of RTL
    if ($variables['html_attributes']['dir'] == 'rtl') {
          $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'themename/rtl';
    }
}
```

Clear the cache and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Just wanted to point out that adding the library to the info.yml file will make it load in every page which is not what we need for multilingual sites.

Comment: Sure thing but I'm not saying that you should add it to info.yml file but libraries file, you can include a library based on your need in twig as well, so it's up to you

Comment: sorry, I haven't seen this answer. nice solution vote up

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a simple module called [Twig RTL Detection](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_rtl_detection) which extends twig and provides a boolean `is_language_rtl` function for twig so you can simply add rtl libraries if this function returns TURE **in any** html.twig files you want.

```
{{ attach_library('my_theme/front') }}
{% if is_language_rtl() %}
  {{ attach_library('my_theme/front_rtl') }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi Alireza, 
nice to see your answer. nice solution. maybe you can add more functionality and create a module  twig_tweak_rtl  ;)

Comment: Hi @Yuseferi, thanks for your reply, I would be glad to hear your ideas about this module, ad how it can be extended using features